# Find by primary key with Hibernate/JPA vs JDBC

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I'm doing a benchmark between two applications, one built with `JPA 2/Hibernate 4` and another one built with `JDBC`. Overall, differences are not too big (less than an order of magnitude).The only exception is when I get records by the primary key.
Using JDBC the time is under 10 ms, and using Hibernate it's never under 60 ms. 
I've installed ehcache, but for this particular query the difference remains the same.
Is there any trick or hack that I'm missing?

**---Edited**

JPA mapping and classes are built with Hibernate Tools, and there's nothing particular about them. JDBC recovers PL/SQL objects from Oracle (which as I've tested on other benchmarks is slower than recovering raw data).

When the complexity of the test increases, the comparation between both technologies gets more even, and eventually Hibernate/JPA is better for some tests (like recovering a lot of complex objects).

The point is that I can't make any operation with Hibernate/JPA that takes less time than about 60 ms. Seems like there's a minimum amount of time that Hibernate/JPA takes to do the least expensive transaction (on this case, recover a record by it's PK). Is there any way to reduce this time?

Comment: can you add a simple example (a bean definition, a create script table...)?

Comment: Bean definitions are created by Hibernate Tools

Comment: Please, add a bean definition and the script table associated

Comment: I'd have to build some mocks. I'll do it as soon as I can.

Comment: a better description of your tests is also in order, as JDBC only returns raw data and JPA has to build entities from that same data.

Comment: Hibernate will never be as fast as pure JDBC, hibernate is built on JBDC and adds developer friendly features that add overhead to its queries, and it tells you this in the spec under [Best practices]{http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch26.html}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just checking elapsed time you could profile the execution in order to see what does Hibernate do during that time. You'd check what @Andrei I says. Most of the overhead is likely to happen because of object instantiation and reflection operations. Since an id search will return less data, Hibernate overhead is likely to be more noticeable.

Comment: Ok, but do you know how to reduce that overhead?

Comment: You probably can't. Maybe you could enable some caching to avoid database interaction, but it might be seen as cheating. It's the tradeoff of using JPA/Hibernate: you get a powerful tool, a plus of productivity and mantainability in return of some performance plus. I use to say that it allows you to focus your effort at business and key performance points, instead of overoptimizing every query.